# What is the code of the ta.vwap built-in function in Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, average, anchor, volume, price

What is the code of the ta.vwap built-in function in Tradingview?
The functions arguments are:

- source
- anchor
- stdev_mult

But, what is the background code?